# read japanese character in R Studio

Tags: r, cjk

I have a japanese text csv file seperated by tab
It was written in utf-8 using python csv package
However,when i import it with command in RStudio as below

```
A <- read.csv("reviews4.csv",sep="\t",header = F,encoding="UTF-8")
```

The japanese character would show like this:

```
<U+8AAC>明無<U+3057><U+306B><U+5185>容量<U.....
```

I think it only shows kanji parts correctly.

I've tried encoding = "CP932"
It would show:
隤祆<98><81><86>捆<87><....

Then I tried another way: click the file in the lower right and select "import dataset"
Then strange things happend:
When I choose "First rows as names",the colnames show japanese properly
but when I disable that,it show uncorrectly.

[image]
Can anyone help me importing japanese csv properly?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Use fileEncoding="UTF-8" instead of encoding="UTF-8".